# Retrieving a List of Declared Constants?

Tags: excel, vba, constants

I'm using a list of constants to group all the strings I might need to edit all in one place:

```
Public Const project = "XXXX-"
Public Const filepath = "Z:\Operations\Projects\XXXXXXX\"
Public Const tracker = "20YY XXXX WO Tracker.xlsm"
Public Const WOarchive = "Archive\"
Public Const WOfolder = "20YY WOs\"
Public Const WOtemplates = "WO Templates\"
Public Const template001 = "template1_filename.xlsx"
Public Const template003 = "template3_filename.xlsx"
Public Const template005 = "template5_filename.xlsx"
Public Const template007 = "template7_filename.xlsx"
Public Const template009 = "template9_filename.xlsx"
```

I want to populate a combobox in a form with the names of these constants for error-checking reasons, but I can't seem to find what that collection is called. The search results are all articles about how to declare constants. Is this possible?

Comment: You could look at VBA Extensibility, so for example, a quick test for me was `? p.VBComponents("Module2").CodeModule.Lines(1,p.VBComponents("Module2").CodeModule.CountOfDeclarationLines)` which returns `Public Const csttest As String = "test"` where p is `Set p = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject`

Comment: Take a look at [Excel Worksheet Combo Boxes](https://www.contextures.com/excelworksheetcomboboxes.html)

Comment: I'd create a class for this.  Put the strings in a ScriptingDictionary.  Create an enumeration that acts as the keys for the string.  Implement Property get Iterm, Function Keys and Funtion Items.  You can then use the Items array to populate the combo box.

Comment: ^ This. Don't mess around with VBA Extensibility.

Comment: Yes, but this is a way to NOT use constants and does not answer the question.

Comment: @ExcelHero - but presumably one *shouldn't* use constants here... it's an XY problem IMO.

Comment: Would a Scripting Dictionary be available to all my other modules as public constants are?

Comment: If you declare it in project/global scope, then it's in project/global scope...

Answer (score 3):

This solution is the ONLY answer to YOUR question... but that does not mean you should do this. You are using constants for maintainability, which is a good thing, but VBA code is not accessible by other VBA code by default for security purposes. So for your scenario, using an alternative to constants would be better. Others have suggested using a Dictionary. You could also use [CustomXMLParts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.customxmlparts), which have the advantage of persistence.

That being said, the only way to get the names of the constants is to parse the text of the code module that contains the constants.

To read the text of any code module,  you will need to set a reference to:

```
Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3 type library
```

...in Tools-->References in the VB IDE.

Then you can retrieve a module's declarations like so...

```
With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("YOUR_CODE_MODULE_NAME").CodeModule

    MsgBox .Lines(1, .CountOfDeclarationLines)

End With
```

Comment: Can I late-bind this reference?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Other users will be using this macro and I don't want to have to go around and tell everyone to set up a reference... am I confused here?

Comment: @BreadDoughlas yes. VBIDE API would be the same DLL version on every Windows box ever built in this century AFAIK. And working late-bound against a library you're not familiar with, is basically like coding blindfolded and you get no compiler validation and all the annoyances of late-binding. I'd be more worried about having to go around and enable programmatic access to the VBIDE API for everyone, lowering the entire company's security just because we want to be parsing code instead of using a dictionary.

Comment: Because the missing footnote here, is that programmatic access to the VBIDE API is blocked, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: One more thing: `Const foo As Long = 42, bar = "abc"` is valid, as is `Const _{newline}foo = _{newline}    42`. Parsing is *a lot* of fun, but belongs in a parsing-dedicated project. This answer answers OP's question as asked, but I agree with BigBen this is absolutely an X-Y problem.

Comment: Please select an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a scripting.dictionary solution

Class ComboTxt

```
Option Explicit

Public Enum ComboYourNameTexts
    NotDefined = -1
    Project
    filepath
    tracker
    WOarchive
    WOfolder
    WOtemplates
    template001
    template003
    template005
    template007
    template009
End Enum

Private Type State

    Host                            As Scripting.Dictionary

End Type

Private s                           As State

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    If s.Host Is Nothing Then

        Set s.Host = New Scripting.dicitonary

    End If

    With s.Host

        .Add Project, "XXXX-"
        .Add filepath, "Z:\Operations\Projects\XXXXXXX\"
        .Add tracker, "20YY XXXX WO Tracker.xlsm"
        .Add WOarchive, "Archive\"
        .Add WOfolder, "20YY WOs\"
        .Add WOtemplates, "WO Templates\"
        .Add template001, "template1_filename.xlsx"
        .Add template003, "template3_filename.xlsx"
        .Add template005, "template5_filename.xlsx"
        .Add template007, "template7_filename.xlsx"
        .Add template009, "template9_filename.xlsx"

    End With

End Sub

Public Property Get Item(ByVal Key As ComboYourNameTexts)
    Item = s.Host.Item(Key)
End Property

'@Description("Returns a variant array containing the Keys of the scripting Dictionary (values of the enum ComboYourNameTexts)
Public Function Keys() As Variant
    Keys = s.Host.Keys
End Function

'@Description("Returns a variant array containg the strings put into the scripting dictionary")
Public Function Items() As Variant
    Items = s.Host.Items
End Function

Public Function Count() As Long
    Count = s.Host.Count
End Function
```

Example of use

```
DIm myCmb as ComboTxt
Set myCmb = new ComboTxt

Dim myEnum as variant
For each myEnum in myCmb  ' scripting dictionaries return the Key not the value

    'Do something with myCmb.Item(myEnum)   'NB you will get intellisense for your enum when you type the (

Next
```

or even

```
myComboBox = myCmb.Items  'if my memory serves me correctly
```